# Slow socket_accept in PHP

Tags: php, sockets, tcp

I am trying to implement a simple socket server which accepts TCP connections and returns a response according to the input.
The entire program is running in a loop so that it is always on, but there is a significant delay before the `socket_accept` function call.

When I execute the program, it takes about 10-15 seconds for the first echo "The server is ready" command to be executed.

I'm running this on a RedHat Enterprise Linux Server 5.5 (Tikanga) with PHP v. 5.1.6.

Any suggestions?

Code Snippet:

```
$host = "SERVER_IP";
$port = 80;
set_time_limit(100);
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
if (!socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)) { 
    echo socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)); 
exit; 
}
$result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not create socket\n");
$result = socket_listen($socket, 3) or die("Could not set up socket listener\n");

while(true)
{
    $spawn = socket_accept($socket) or die("Could not accept incoming connection\n");
    echo "\nThe server is ready\n";
    $input = socket_read($spawn, 1024) or die("Could not read input\n");

    $output = processInput($input);

    socket_write($spawn, $output, strlen ($output)) or die("Could not write output\n");
    socket_close($spawn);

}   
socket_close($socket);
echo "\nTerminating\n";
```

Comment: Use a different port. 80 is usually reserved for HTTP protocol, you might be having clashes with another service listening at that port.

Comment: I checked that. And I tried a different port also. Same thing :(

Comment: The problem is, its too slow?

Comment: Yep. I feel I am doing something fundamentally wrong here.

Comment: Hm maybe the resolving of your local hostname goes wrong and takes a lot of time? If its on the same server...

Comment: Is it only the first response or are all slow?

Comment: @powtac : The delay is present every time the loop runs. And as far as resolving the hostname, I am giving the IPAddress, and am listening on the same server as this script is running on.

Comment: Can you move line
    $spawn = socket_accept($socket) or die("Could not accept incoming connection\n");
    echo "\nThe server is ready\n";
 out of the while?

Comment: The client sends a message and closes the connection.
So, it needs to be inside the loop only, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

socket_accept is a blocking method and it doesn't return unless it accepts a new socket connection. so your code will not print "The server is ready" unless your client calls a socket connect function and make a successful connection to your socket server. So the delay could be at your client end or maybe you are running your client after 10 to 15 seconds.

Comment: I don't think that is it. Cause I can make the connection only after that message is displayed. I think something is wrong with the server. I shall check that.

Comment: Its like that. Please check the documentation. The socket_accept is a blocking function and it doesn't return until there is error or successful connection. http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-accept.php

Comment: Thanks. I figured out the problem. Moved the spawn command outside the loop. That seemed to work. Thanks @Powtac